# Exporting Google Cloud User Accounts to AppEngine's Datastore Emulator

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, ndb

I am working with an older AppEngine GCP application and I am trying to setup a local environment with an emulated representation of the user profiles stored in datastore. For this, I am trying to export the gmail user-profiles from my GCP workspace and import these into my datastore emulator.

Is the local ndb datastore and the datastore emulator completely disconnected from eachother? Because I cant seem to interact with the data imported to the emulator. Is it possible to import it to my local datastore.db directly?

So far, this is what I am doing:
I went into GCP and exported the datastore contents as a folder with gzip files. I unpacked them and stored them on my computer.

I run my dev_appserver.py with "--support_datastore_emulator true" so that I get a datastore emulator port, then I use this in postman:

POST request - localhost:[my emulator port]/v1/projects/[my project]:import

body - {"input_url":"path/to/exported_data.overall_export_metadata"}

The request is successful, but I cant seem to find any update to my local ndb database. I can add new and query for ndb elements in the admin interactive console on http://localhost:8000/console, but none of the imported elements can be queried for.

I run the app with:

```
dev_appserver.py . --storage_path .tmp/ --support_datastore_emulator true --enable_console --dev_appserver_log_level=debug
```

And the emulator with

```
datastore start --data-dir=.tmp/ --project=[MY-PROJECT-ID]
```

I get this warning when starting the emulator:

> WARNING: Reusing existing data in [.tmp/].

Which is kinda what I want, no? Since I want my local datastore and the emulator data to both be accessible through ndb calls.

I have added the following environment variables:

```
DATASTORE_DATASET=[MY-PROJECT-ID]
DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8081
DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH=http://localhost:8081/datastore
DATASTORE_HOST=http://localhost:8081;DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=[MY-PROJECT-ID]
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\path\to\service_account_key.json
```

Comment: As you mentioned `I unpacked them and stored them on my computer` .  But as per this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/emulator-export-import#load_emulator_data_into_your_database) Before you can load entities exported from the emulator into your database, you must upload your entity export files to a Cloud Storage bucket. The managed import feature reads only from Cloud Storage buckets.

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni, that's strange, since I have been able to see that the elements are in my emulated datastore; this by importing them from my local destination. My issue is rather that I cannot seem to access the emulated values through ndb query-commands. I can query for the models that have been added to ndb by using .put() though..

Comment: Can you check the output by running the command [`--dev_appserver_log_level=debug`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/tools/migrate-cloud-datastore-emulator#getting_emulator_output) to see the output of Datastore Emulator.

Comment: When starting dev_appserver, I get the following output regarding my datastore:
"WARNING: Detected environment variable DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8081, dev_appserver will speak to the Cloud Datastore emulator running on this address. The datastore_path .tmp/datastore.db will be neglected.
If you want datastore to store on .tmp/datastore.db, remove DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST from environment variables and restart dev_appserver"

Comment: Prior to running dev_appserver, I start my datastore emulator host at 8081 pointing towards my local directory ".tmp". I detailed it a bit more in my comment answering NoCommandLine :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the order in which you executed the steps but try this

1. [Start](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#starting_the_emulator) datastore emulator by running

   `gcloud beta emulators datastore start --data-dir=[DATA_DIR]`
2. The above command should now give you a `port` number. You should note that the port number can change each time you start the emulator.
3. [Import](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/emulator-export-import) the data you exported from the cloud using the port number you got when you started the emulator (bullet 1).
4. **Before** you can run `dev_appserver.py`, you **need to set** the environment variables using the values from when you started the emulator (bullet 1). You can either set the values automatically or manually (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#manually_setting_the_variables))
5. Now that the environment variables have been set, you can now run `dev_appserver.py` using

   `dev_appserver.py --support_datastore_emulator=true app.yaml`

Comment: Hi! I am pretty much already doing all of that. To start the emulator, I use "gcloud beta emulators datastore start --data-dir=.tmp/ --project=[MY-PROJECT-ID]".
I set all environment variables prior to running by setting them in my IDE run config, and I use "DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8081" for the emulator, so it is always directed towards localhost:8081.

Comment: Okay. If something else occurs to me, I'll update. I achieve the same thing a different way (our App allows us to export the data from Prod as JSON and then import it into Dev)